# Clickonce applications: Update to a different project?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I have a clickonce application that has a console application foo.exe which simply launches a windows forms application bar.exe. I deployed it using visual studio to a network share. Life happened and I no longer have the project that I used to publish the original clickonce application. I need to replace the bar.exe windows froms application. 
What is a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MageUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Make sure you back up your full deployment before doing anything. Then replace the bar.exe file

Open the application manifest (the one *without* the .application extension), save, and re-sign. Then open the deployment manifest (the one *with* the .application extension), save, and re-sign.

You could use the command line version of Mage as well, but for a one-off scenario, the UI version will be easier.

Comment: I tried reproducing the exact steps listed above. when I try saving the application manifest to sign it, it gives me a warning saying "One or more referenced files were not found". [The bar.exe that I need to replace actually looks like bar.exe.deploy in the application files folder. When I replace it, I delete the old bar.exe.deploy and paste the new bar.exe and edit the file extension to make it bar.exe.deploy. I uncheck the "add .deploy file extension to any that don't have it" because otherwise it adds the .deploy extension to my deployment manifest which resides in the same folder.]

Comment: If I ignore the error and proceed, I cannot launch the application and it says "version field '' is invalid in the manifest"

Comment: OK, shooting from the hip here. I haven't actually set up a scenario and tried it all out. Take the deployment manifest out of the folder while you're updating the application manifest. I would try to leave the "add .deploy extension..." since that's the way it was before. Another thing I forgot to mention. Make sure you increase the version numbers in your manifests. And finally, to be safe, in the deployment manifest's 'Application Reference' section, re-select the application manifest before you save it. Whew, I'm sure there's still more, but give this a try.

Comment: This works! One thing to watch out for though: there's a known bug in Mage that replaces empty space with %20 which is not recognized if you publish to a network share. So if your path has folders like "Application Files", i'd replace the space with an underscore or something.